# How to avoid repetitions of code using webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I'm doing multiple page app and using vue.js components for my UI so my output file structure looks like:

```
common.js
page1
--page1.css
--page1.js
--page1.html
page2
--page2.css
--page2.js
--page2.html
and so on...
```

My webpack.config file:
https://gist.github.com/lavezzi1/5bb6db29a19a2ca4b1ec08c4a01b19f5

My typical entry file looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './app';

import Toast from '@library/toast';

require('@blocks/base');

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {Toast},
  data: {
      msg: 'Dashboard page'
  }
})
```

Now I have 42 pages. So if I make npm run build and then concatenate all of css files (for example) it weighs about 2mb, if every page contains button this css file contains 42 duplication of this component.

I believe the same problem with js. One guy from github recommend me do this https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3104#issuecomment-256319225

Make vendor file. So I did this:

```
const entriesPlusVendor = Object.assign({}, entries, {
  vendor: ['vue']
});

module.exports = {
    entry: entriesPlusVendor,
```

The vendor.js and common.js files are created now but contains the same code (vue code) but common.js a little bigger.

Any help guys, I am stuck with it.

UPD: Recenly I found this repo https://github.com/lincenying/vue2-multiple-entry its works very well, create vendor.js and common.js as expected, but doesn't fit to my file structure.